# Convergence of a sum related to prime gaps

Tags: convergence-divergence, prime-gaps

Let $p_n$ denote the $n$th prime, starting from $p_0=2$.  For each positive integer $i$, let $f(i)$ denote the least $n$ such that $p_{n+1}-p_n=2i$.  So for instance, $f(1)=1$ (corresponding to $p_1=3$ and $p_2=5$), $f(2)=3$ (corresponding to $p_3=7$ and $p_4=11$), $f(3)=8$ (corresponding to $p_8=23$ and $p_9=29$), and $f(4)=23$ (corresponding to $p_{23}=89$ and $p_{24}=97$).

If there is no prime gap of size $2i$ (though it is conjectured that each even number is a prime gap infinitely often, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polignac%27s_conjecture)), we omit $i$ from the sum below (or set $f(i)=\infty$ formally, which amounts to the same thing).

My question is:

> Does the sum
>   $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{f(i)}=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{23}\cdots$$
>   converge or diverge?

Comment: It is very difficult to understand how $f(2) = 8$ is the "*n*th odd prime that is before a gap of composites size" $2$.  You present a sum of reciprocals and then spring a question about the sum of $f(n)$.  Is some editing/clarification in order?

Comment: Then why is f(2) = 8?  8 is not the first prime with a gap of 2 between it and the next prime.  i) There are no primes with a gap of 2 (gap of 2 means a difference of 3) and ii) 8 isn't prime.  So I don't understand you definition of f(x).

Comment: I do not understand the definition of $f(i)$, too. Moreover, you should be interested in $\sum_{i\geq 0}\frac{1}{f(i)}$, not $\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty}f(i)$.

Comment: If $f(i)=\min\{k\in\mathbb{N}: p_{k+1}-p_{k}\geq i\}$? If so, please state it clearly.

Comment: Okay, if f(x) is the *ordered index* of the first prime (*not* the prime itself) then, I figure f(0) = 1 because $p_1 = 2$ and $p_2 = 3$ and there are zero composites between 2 and 3.  But f(1) = 2 as $p_2 = 3$ and $p_3 = 5$ and there is a gap of 1.  f(3) =4 (as $p_4 = 7$ and between 7 and 11 there are three composites).  f(2)  is undefined as there are no two primes with 2 composites between them.  If as @JackD'Aurizio states it's the min then f(1) =2, f(2) = 4, f(3) also equals 4.  So I'm still lost.

Comment: I have rewritten the question to be clearer about the definition of $f(i)$ (and also to correct that $f(4)=23$, not $24$).  If I have misinterpreted what you meant, please feel free to revert and/or further edit.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Eric Wolfsey made an edit to this question. Maybe it makes more sense now?

Comment: @hardmath edits made

Comment: @EricWofsey thanks for the edits

Comment: Is it even clear that $f(i)$ is defined for all $i$? (What if a certain gap never occurs?)

Comment: I don't think it is known whether f(i) exists for all i.But if we restrict ourselves to the values of f(i) that do exist,  I suspect that the Q is either very deep or not yet answerable even by advanced methods.

Answer (score 1):

By the prime number theorem, $p_n= (1+o(1))n\log n$. This shows that
$$
p_{n+1}-p_n = O(\log n) + o(n\log n) = o(n\log n) .
$$
If we use a [more accurate approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number) of the same type, we can easily improve this to
$$
p_{n+1}-p_n = o(n/\log^2 n) .
$$
This implies that $f(k)\gtrsim k\log^2 k$, so the series converges.